# local variables scope in anonymous function objects in Ruby

Tags: ruby

David. A. Black stated in his book:

> "blocks can serve as the bodies of anonymous function objects, and those objects preserve the local variables that are in scope at the time of their creation—even if the function objects get handed around other local scopes."

Can anyone help me here to understand what means with some examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create an anonymous function (a [lambda](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-lambda) or [Proc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Proc.html)), you give it a block, which is the body of the function, like so:

```
-> { this_is_the_function_body }
Proc.new { this_is_the_function_body }
```

A block retains all the local variables as they existed in the scope in which the block was created:

```
def my_lambda
  text = 'foo bar baz'
  -> { "text is: #{text}" }
end

l = my_lambda
text       #=> #<NameError: undefined local variable or method `text' for main:Object>
l.inspect  #=> "#<Proc:0x007f9863865a80@(pry):3 (lambda)>"
l.call     #=> "foo bar baz"
```

As we see above, the local variable `text` is still available even though even the lambda object resides in, and is called in, a scope in which `text` doesn’t exist. This is even true if a local variable with the same name exists in the calling scope:

```
text = 'something else'
l.call  #=> "foo bar baz"
```

This is called a *[closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29)*. No matter where you call the function, you still have access to the scope in which it was created.

This doesn’t just apply to local variables, though, but instead the whole scope, as we can see here:

```
class C
  def f; -> { g }; end
  def g; 'foo'; end
end

C.new.f.call  #=> "foo"
```

Comment: Okay! nice what he means by `even if the function objects get handed around other local scopes."`?

Comment: @iAmRubuuu You can pass around the function object as much as you want and it doesn’t affect the fact that it retains access to the original scope. This happens in the example above when the lambda is returned from the method—once it exists outside the method it is in a different local scope.

Comment: I understood your answer very well and it is very explanatory. But couldn't still connect myself with the above line as in my first comment?

Comment: @iAmRubuuu If you understand the above, you understand that quote. It simply says that when you use the function object in any different scope it still retains that original scope.